# Terminating dask workers after jobs are done

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to make use of dask on a cluster and I'm interested in terminating all the workers as soon as all the jobs are done.
I was trying to do that with the retire_workers method, but that doesn't seem to kill the workers.
Here is an example.

```
import time
import os
from dask.distributed import Client

def long_func(x):
    time.sleep(2)
    return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    C = Client(scheduler_file='sched.json')
    res = []
    for _ in range(10):
        res.append(C.submit(long_func, _))
    for r in res:
        r.result()
    workers = list(C.scheduler_info()['workers'])
    # C.run(lambda: os._exit(0), workers=workers)
    C.retire_workers(workers=workers, close_workers=True)
```

The scheduler and a worker were started with these commands:

```
dask-scheduler --scheduler-file sched.json 
dask-worker --scheduler-file sched.json --nthreads=1 --lifetime='5minutes'
```

The hope was that after executing the python code above, the worker would terminate (after 20 seconds), but it does not, staying for the whole 5 minutes. Any advice how to fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will shutdown the connected scheduler and retire the workers:

```py
C.shutdown()
```

Comment: You will probably want to also run `C.close()` after that to avoid receiving messages about the missing scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using a context manager to manage the cluster - its nice and clean. I've had issues when it comes to RAM memory getting maxed out and stalling my computer when working locally, but here is an example of what I frequently use:

```py
# start our Dask cluster
from dask.distributed import Client,LocalCluster

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cluster = LocalCluster()
    
    with Client(cluster) as client:
        print("scheduler host: ", client.scheduler.address)
        # do some stuff
```