# How to have Dask workers terminate when done?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I can't just shut down the entire cluster like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66057630/4230643) because there might be other jobs running. I run one cluster in order to avoid having to use Kubernetes. Jobs get submitted to this cluster, but they call into C libraries that leak memory.

The workers run one thread per process, so it would be acceptable to terminate the entire worker process and have it be restarted.

I can't just use os.kill from the task itself because the task's return value has to be propagated back through Dask. I have to get Dask to terminate the process for me at the right time.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what kind of cluster are you using? have you tried using [`cluster.adapt`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/adaptive.html)?

Comment: If you want to terminate workers because of memory leaks, these worker memory management features added in the newer dask versions might be helpful: https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker.html#memory-not-released-back-to-the-os

Comment: I looked at the man page for `mallopt` and it says the default trim threshold is 128 KB. So I should never expect to see any process on Linux wasting hundreds of megabytes unless Dask is calling `mallopt(M_TRIM_THRESHOLD, -1)` which would be a bug in Dask, or the C library called by my task is doing that, probably on the assumption that the kernel would clean things up when the process exits, which Dask violates by maintaining permanent worker processes. If I could just get Dask to not violate assumptions made in code I don't control, it would help.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I'm running a static cluster made of GCP instances, and there are multiple clients, so I can't just call `cluster.adapt` from one of the clients as it would interfere with the work submitted by the other clients.